# Minimize, then Maximize a Window

Tags: windows

For Windows 11, I know that I can use `Win + Down Arrow` to minimize the current window.

To have the same window pop up again, what key can I use?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec

Comment: Adding the SPECIFIC version of windows might help.  Please respond by updating your tags.  This behavior is always under modification.

Comment: Probable that alt-tab is your answer.

Comment: The trouble with minimising a window is that it's no longer in focus, so you can't just maximise it again because the system doesn't know which window you mean.

Comment: **If** that window has *just* been minimized, Win+UpArrow **restores** it to previous size (not maximized).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That's the first thing I tried. I wouldn't be asking this question if it was that basic...

Comment: @JossieCalderon, it works on my Win 10 PC's

Comment: It works on mine too

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Maximizing back the same window immediately after minimizing (otherwise how would it know which window you want to maximize? And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> would be the way to go) then +<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> should do the trick to restore the Window.

Comment: That doesn't work. It's the first thing I tried.

Comment: Works for me on Windows 11, you may have something else going on

Answer (score 1):

When using Win+Down-Arrow to minimize the current window, you may
immediately restore it by pressing Win+Up-Arrow.
However, this has to be done without letting go of the Win key,
since letting go of it causes Windows to forget which window
it just minimized.

You may use the free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to add this feature to Windows.

The following script will define the following hotkeys:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> : minimize the currently active window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> : restore the last-minimized window

Here is the script :

```
win := ""
^Down::
WinGet, win, ID, A
WinMinimize, ahk_id %win%
return
^Up::
WinRestore, ahk_id %win%
win := ""
return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)